# how to correct "incorrect padding" on private key

Tags: python

The error is "incorrect padding" when I try to pass a private key to access an sftp server. I created the key by running PuttyGen Conversion/Export OpenSSH key. I just started. This is what I have and am getting an error. The path is on my desktop. I'm trying to get it to work before moving it elsewhere i.e. the blob.

'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

```
import paramiko

key = paramiko.hostkeys.HostKeys(filename="key path")
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the whole traceback.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding some ='s to the end - the key is probably encoded in base64 and = is the padding character (empty bytes that don't mean anything). add 1 equal and then 2 equals, if that doesn't work then I don't know.

Comment: That didn't work, thank you. What should a key file padding be? I can try to reformat the file.